Using IntelliJ inside Docker
I'm new to Docker so I don't know if this is stricly possible.
We are researching ways of having an image of our Development environment, so everytime a new developer incorporate to the company he can just have access to the image development-enrionment with everything inside and just code.
I know that for example this can be done in AWS. Just having an AMI that is used for different instances of EC2 and for not losing the data just use EBS for the project, data, and if you update the AMI you still have all your project data inside EBS.
Is it possible to do the same with Docker?
Is possible to have IntelliJ, some DB management (MySQL Workbench), java version installed, Wildfly, etc inside a Docker container that uses files from our local files like the root to the project inside C:\Users\myname\projectname\project?
Thanks in advance.

Running GUI applications inside a container is tricky at best, especially if your host system isn't native Linux.  A container also normally only runs a single process, and maybe it could be the IDE, but adding more things to it adds complexity.  A virtual machine is almost certainly a better match.
